# how to create a view in database1, based on a table in database2

Tags: mysql, view, phpmyadmin

I'm using mysql and phpmyadmin. 
I would like to create a view in database1 using a base table that exists in database2 on the same server.

What I've done so far is, I connect to database1 using phpmyadmin and run the following select statement:

```
select * from `database2`.`category`
```

That correctly displays the data from database2.  Then i click on the "create view" link at the bottom of the page... but I can see that it's redirected me to database2. And when i click on OK to save the view, sure enough, it's been created in database2. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried executing this command in database1?

```
create view v_category as
    select * from `database2`.`category`;
```